# Connecting 4 tables to 1 table

Tags: mysql

customer:

```
customer_ID (PK)
other columns with data
```

product:

```
product_ID (PK)
other columns with data
```

Store:

store_ID (PK)
other columns with data

Time:

time_ID (PK)
other columns with data

sales_facts
???

How would I go about connecting those 4 tables to the sales_facts table so all of the information can be queried through the sales_facts table? Would I create the sales_facts with a PK and connect the other 4 with PKs or FKs?

Comment: Linking is a term used in a query where the relation between the rows from separate tabgles is set by according condition (in ON clause or in WHERE clause). You need to set FOREIGN KEY data reference which is a rule for data integrity checking subsystem. What column of what table to what column of what table must refer to - this is defined by the logic of your system.

Comment: So would i connect them by the ID column for each table?